# How to change General options in js dynamically?

Tags: jquery-jtable

I've just started to use jtable in my project and I am having a problem. After creating a jTable instance, I want to change some General options of this instance, but it doesn't seem work.

For example,

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
$('#PersonTableContainer').jtable({
    title: 'Table of people',
    actions: {
        listAction: '/GettingStarted/PersonList',
        createAction: '/GettingStarted/CreatePerson',
        updateAction: '/GettingStarted/UpdatePerson',
        deleteAction: '/GettingStarted/DeletePerson'
    },
    fields: {
        PersonId: {
            key: true,
            list: false
        },
        Name: {
            title: 'Author Name',
            width: '40%'
        },
        Age: {
            title: 'Age',
            width: '20%'
        },
        RecordDate: {
            title: 'Record date',
            width: '30%',
            type: 'date',
            create: false,
            edit: false
        }
    }
});
$('#PersonTableContainer').jtable({ title:'chang title'});  //this doesn't work 
// below also doesn't work
$.extend(true, $.hik.jtable.prototype.options, {title: 'change title'} );
});
```

How can I change General options, Field options and Actions of jtable dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you found the answer, but I run into the same problem and found this working for changing the table's title:

```
$('#PersonTableContainer').find('.jtable-title-text').html('change title');
```

Answer (score 0):

option values are stored in the $.hik.jtable.prototype.options object.
Ex. `$.hik.jtable.prototype.options.columnResizable = false;`
you can check here: http://www.jtable.org/ApiReference#Overview for more info.